# How to create one box plot using multiple columns and argument "split"

Tags: r, graphics, split, dataframe, boxplot

I need create a box plot from a data.frame with **three numeric columns**, and use the argument **split** to separate the boxes by **paint**. I have a large data.frame, but what I need is in the example below:

```
paint<-c("blue", "black", "red", "blue", "black", "red", "blue", "black", "red")
car1<-c(100, 138, 123, 143, 112, 144, 343, 112, 334)
car2<-c(111, 238, 323, 541, 328, 363, 411, 238, 313)
car3<-c(432, 123, 322, 342, 323, 522, 334, 311, 452)
data<-data.frame(paint, car1, car2, car3)

>data
      paint  car1 car2 car3
   1  blue   100  111  432
   2  black  138  238  123
   3  red    123  323  322
   4  blue   143  541  342
   5  black  112  328  323
   6  red    144  363  522
   7  blue   343  411  334
   8  black  112  238  311
   9  red    334  313  452
```

**When I used only one column the following function works:**

boxplot(split(data[,2], data[,1]))

**But when I try to create a boxplot using *three columns* the function does not work:**

boxplot(split(data[,2:4], data[,1]))

Thanks for the help and sorry for poor English.

Comment: What do you want your graph to look like? What's on x axis? Color with three boxplots (for car1, car2 and car3) per color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting your data into long form first and then plotting:

```
temp = reshape(data, direction="long", varying=2:4, sep="")
boxplot(split(temp[,3], temp[,1]))
# boxplot(car ~ paint, data=temp) ### Formula notation, easier to read
```

[image]

Or, use `lattice`:

```
library(lattice)
bwplot(car1 + car2 + car3 ~ paint, data=data)
```

I'm not sure why that notation doesn't work with base R's `boxplot` though.

[image]

## Update

In case I misinterpreted your original question (after reading Roman's comment), here's an option (again using `lattice`) that puts boxplots for `car1`, `car2`, and `car3` separately but side-by-side. This uses the long-form data `temp` created in the first example:

```
bwplot(car ~ paint | paste0("Car ", time), data = temp)
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect this last three-panel lattice plot is what OP's after.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, that occurred to me after I read your comment. @RhinoBR, if you wanted separate plots for each car instead of this panel output, you can also do this with your original data: `lapply(data[-1], function(x) boxplot(x ~ data$paint))`.