# Boxplot of multiple columns in `R` using ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, boxplot

I simply wanted to create a boxplot of three numeric columns of a dataframe in `R`. The dataframe looks like this:

```
  no_filter                      filter1                   filter2
1 0.7223437                    0.7376562                    0.7418750
2 0.7223437                    0.7376562                    0.7418750
3 0.7262500                    0.7276562                    0.7289062
```

I had a look here [How to create one box plot using multiple columns and argument "split"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495406/how-to-create-one-box-plot-using-multiple-columns-and-argument-split), but didn't really get my head around it. So if anyone has an idea, would be super appreciated. In the best case with `gpplot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ggplot`, we may need to reshape into 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
      geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

###data

```
df1 <- structure(list(no_filter = c(0.7223437, 0.7223437, 0.72625), 
    filter1 = c(0.7376562, 0.7376562, 0.7276562), filter2 = c(0.741875, 
    0.741875, 0.7289062)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```